# Optional Authentication in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, passport.js, nestjs

I want to know if there is a decorator that makes the `req.user` object available in a controller method, if the user is logged in (Authaurization header sent), if not then just let the `req.user` be null.

The `AuthGuard` decorator will return 401 if the user is not logged in, so it's not suitable for my case.

Comment: If you have not already, have a look at: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no built-in decorator but you can easily create one yourself. See the example from the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators):

```
import { createParamDecorator } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

export const User = createParamDecorator((data, req) => {
  return req.user;
});
```

Since the built-in `AuthGuard` throws an exception, you can create your own version and overwrite the request handler:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {

  handleRequest(err, user, info) {
    // no error is thrown if no user is found
    // You can use info for logging (e.g. token is expired etc.)
    // e.g.: if (info instanceof TokenExpiredError) ...
    return user;
  }

}
```

Make sure that you are not throwing errors in your `JwtStrategy`:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: 'secretKey',
    });
  }

  async validate(payload) {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(payload);
    // in the docs an error is thrown if no user is found
    return user;
  }
}
```

Then you can use it in your `Controller` like this:

```
@Get()
@UseGuards(MyAuthGuard)
getUser(@User() user) {
  return {user};
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Could not find it looking all over stackoverflow and githubs.

Comment: I cannot find the @User decorator

Comment: @jeromerg It is a custom decoator that is defined in the very first code snippet of this answer.

Answer (score 22):

Another way of doing this is by creating an anonymous passport strategy:

```
// In anonymous.strategy.ts
@Injectable()
export class AnonymousStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'anonymous') {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  authenticate() {
    return this.success({})
  }
}
```

Then, chaining this strategy in the controller:

```
// In create-post.controller.ts
@Controller()
export class CreatePostController {
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard(['jwt', 'anonymous'])) // first success wins
  @Post('/posts')
  async createPost(@Req() req: Request, @Body() dto: CreatePostDto) {
    const user = req.user as ExpressUser

    if (user.email) {
      // Do something if user is authenticated
    } else {
      // Do something if user is not authenticated
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think using this is more flexible. Because sometimes We need to reject the Unauthenticated user.

Comment: I implemented it with my Graphql Guard

```
import { Injectable, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common'
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport'
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql'

@Injectable()
export class EveryoneGqlAuthGuard extends AuthGuard(['jwt', 'anonymous']) {
  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context)
    return ctx.getContext().req
  }
}

```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a public decorator

```
//decorator.ts
export const IS_PUBLIC_KEY = 'AllAnonymous';
export const AllAnonymous = () => SetMetadata(IS_PUBLIC_KEY, true);
```

Then in your JWT guard

```
//JWT authguard.ts
@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {
    super();
  }
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    return super.canActivate(context);
  }

  handleRequest(err: any, user: any, info: any, context: ExecutionContext) {
    const isPublic = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<boolean>(IS_PUBLIC_KEY, [
      context.getHandler(),
      context.getClass(),
    ]);

    if (isPublic && !user) {
      return null;
    }

    if (err || !user) {
      throw err || new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

You can now allow anonymous access in the controller to include the user in the request when the user is authenticated

```
//controller.ts
  @AllAnonymous()
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @Get('profile')
  getUserProfile(@Req() req: any) {
    {
      const { user } = req;

      console.log(user);

      return user
    }
  }
```